# insert into en tablas relacionadas cuando tengo muchos id_

Tags: mysql

Soy nuevo en `SQL` y me he encontrado con un problema que seguro tiene fácil solución, al hacer un `insert into` en tablas relacionadas con llave foránea, por ejemplo:

```
INSERT INTO tabla (col1, col2, col3, id_?) VALUES (val1, val2, val3, (numero id_?)
```

Si tengo pocos registros el `(numero id_?)` lo busco en la tabla y lo pongo pero si tengo 2000 registros, ¿Como busco el `(numero id_?)` de la llave foránea?, no se si me explico.

Gracias

Comment: Bienvenido Javier Monleon a Stack Overflow en español, te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y de paso ganes tu primer medalla, también es muy importante que leas [ask] para poder mejorar tu pregunta y que sea bien recibida por la comunidad mejorando tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas..

Comment: Hola Javier, bienvenido a SOes. Primero es necesario que indiques que servidor de bases de datos utilizas (`eg: mysql, sql server, ?`). Segundo, de la forma que esta planteado, pareciera que estas usando un lenguaje del lado del servidor (?) Y finalmente, particularmente yo no termino de entender el por que del problema, ya que de la forma que esta planteado, solo tenes que pedir el último `id` generado por cada `INSERT`.

Comment: ¿Que es lo que buscas hacer? digo, más allá de este problema, ¿cual es la idea de este insert que intentas?

Comment: En la pregunta especifica que quieres logar al final,  si no hay solución tu problema te pueden dar otra manera de lograrlo. ¿Que te llevó a necesitar lograr esto?...

Comment: Hola a todos y gracias por contestar a un novato en SQL y php. Respondo. Uso MySQL y lo utilizo a través de unos formularios php en una página web el localhost de momento mientras monto todo y aprendo a través de xamp . Lo que quiero lograr es que en un momento dado tendré que insertar datos en una tabla relacionada con llave foránea. Que alomejor está en medio de 5 tablas.  Pero como el id es un número natural autoincrementable tendría que ver el la tabla que está relacionada el número id para ponerlo como llave foránea.

Comment: Supongo que tendré que hacer un selec para ver el id que se le puso al dato que yo ya conozco.